# How to import csv file as a training with label and testing with target data for classifier in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn, classification

I have two csv files for training and testing data. Both of them look like this (I only show one of them, but both of them are the same form of data and same attributes name) :

```
Full,Id,Id & PPDB,Id & Words Sequence,Id & Synonyms,Id & Hypernyms,Id & Hyponyms,Gold Standard
1.667,0.476,0.952,0.476,1.429,0.952,0.476,2.345
3.056,1.111,1.667,1.111,3.056,1.389,1.111,1.9
1.765,1.176,1.176,1.176,1.765,1.176,1.176,2.2
0.714,0.714,0.714,0.714,0.714,0.714,0.714,0.0
1.538,0.769,0.769,0.769,1.538,0.769,0.769,2.586
2.188,1.875,1.875,1.875,1.875,2.188,1.875,1.667
3.333,1.333,1.333,1.333,3.333,2.0,1.333,2.8
2.5,1.667,1.667,1.667,2.222,1.944,1.667,2.481
```

I'm a newbie in scikit-learn. I learn the example of training+label and testing+target data input are like this :

```
X_train = np.array(["new york is a hell of a town",
                    "new york was originally dutch",
                    "the big apple is great",
                    "new york is also called the big apple",
                    "nyc is nice",
                    "people abbreviate new york city as nyc",
                    "the capital of great britain is london",
                    "london is in the uk",
                    "london is in england",
                    "london is in great britain",
                    "it rains a lot in london",
                    "london hosts the british museum",
                    "new york is great and so is london",
                    "i like london better than new york"])
y_train_text = [["new york"],["new york"],["new york"],["new york"],["new york"],
                ["new york"],["london"],["london"],["london"],["london"],
                ["london"],["london"],["new york","london"],["new york","london"]]

X_test = np.array(['nice day in nyc',
                   'welcome to london',
                   'london is rainy',
                   'it is raining in britian',
                   'it is raining in britian and the big apple',
                   'it is raining in britian and nyc',
                   'hello welcome to new york. enjoy it here and london too'])
target_names = ['New York', 'London']
```

is it possible to import my csv files that contain of float numbers as a training with label and testing with target as data input? Also, I want to make `Gold Standard` attribute as my label for training data and target for testing data. If it's possible, how to make that input? Thanks

Comment: Read the csv using pandas and then select X and y from it

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in @Vivek Kumar's comment, you could get the job done by using pandas' [`csv_read`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) like this:

```
In [12]: import pandas as pd

In [13]: import numpy as np

In [14]: df = pd.read_csv('train.txt')

In [15]: X_train = np.asarray(df.iloc[:, :-1])

In [16]: y_train = np.asarray(df.iloc[:, -1])

In [17]: X_train
Out[17]: 
array([[ 1.667,  0.476,  0.952, ...,  1.429,  0.952,  0.476],
       [ 3.056,  1.111,  1.667, ...,  3.056,  1.389,  1.111],
       [ 1.765,  1.176,  1.176, ...,  1.765,  1.176,  1.176],
       ..., 
       [ 2.188,  1.875,  1.875, ...,  1.875,  2.188,  1.875],
       [ 3.333,  1.333,  1.333, ...,  3.333,  2.   ,  1.333],
       [ 2.5  ,  1.667,  1.667, ...,  2.222,  1.944,  1.667]])

In [18]: y_train
Out[18]: array([ 2.345,  1.9  ,  2.2  ,  0.   ,  2.586,  1.667,  2.8  ,  2.481])
```

Please notice I have previously saved the data you provided to file `train.txt`.